# Send array of guid in the parameter list of a get request using PostMan

Tags: api, postman

I have a method in my api Controller which have the following signature

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Controller/GetResult")]
public ApiResult<List<IDocument>> GetResult(DateTime date, Guid id, List<Guid> Ids)
```

I need to call it using PostMan but I don't know how to send the last argument which is a list of Guid in the parameter list, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace all params with **JObject** as following :

**pass JSON:**

```
{"date":"2019-02-17", "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001", "Ids":["00000000-0000-0000-0000-111111111111", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-222222222222"]}
```

**ACTION:**

```
public ApiResult<List<IDocument>> GetResult(JObject json)
    {
        DateTime date = json.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "date"))?.Value.ToString();  // simple parameter
        //----> output: "2019-02-17"


        Guid id = new Guid(json.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "id"))?.Value.ToString());  // simple parameter
        //----> output: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"


        List<JToken> Ids = json.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "Ids")?.Value.ToList(); // list
        //----> output: ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-111111111111", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-222222222222"]


        //you should specify the type of "JToken" values as this:
        List<Guid> IdsList = new List<Guid>();
        foreach (var Id in Ids)
        {
            IdsList.Add(new Guid(Id.Value<string>()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use postman in-build [Dynamic Variable](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/#dynamic-variables) `$guid` .

> This generates a v4 style guid at runtime.

Try this GET request using Postman:

`https://httpbin.org/anything?IDs=["{{$guid}}","{{$guid}}","{{$guid}}"]`